# Embedded jqueryui accordian with Angular

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

How do I create a multiple-level (embedded) jqueryui accordian using Angular?

The layout should have collable sections with this hierarchy:

1. Level 1

   1. Lesson 1
   2. Lesson 2
   3. Lesson 3
2. Level 2

   1. Lesson 1
   2. Lesson 2
   3. Lesson 3

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

HTML

```
        <div ng-controller="startLessonController">
        <div id="accordianLevel">
            <div ng-repeat="level in course.levels" >
              <h2> {{level.number}} - {{level.name}}: {{level.title}}</h2>
                <div >
                    {{level.description}}
                    <div id="accordianLesson">
                        <div ng-repeat="lesson in level.lessons" >
                          <h3> {{lesson.number}} - {{lesson.name}}: {{lesson.title}}</h3>
                             <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="goal in lesson.goals">{{goal}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Angular js with embedded data for testing (truncated)

```
var startLessonApp = angular.module('startLessonApp', []);
startLessonApp.controller('startLessonController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.course = {
"levels": [
 {
  "number": 1,
  "name": "Level One",
  "title": "Conversation Starters",
  "lessons": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "name": "Lesson One"
    }
  ]
 }
};
```

Here is the js to initialize the accordian.  Note the override to explicitly identify the accordian header elements (h2 for Level, and h3 for Lesson)

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#accordianLevel" ).accordion({
        header: "h2",
        collapsible: true,
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
            $( "#accordianLesson" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        header: "h3",
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
  });
}());
```

[image: Result on page]

Comment: You missed ]}; for $scope.course-Array.
But didn't work for me! Maybe in newer Versions of jquery-ui there doesn't have to be an <div> in Front of the header-tag of the accordion (<h2>) ?!